# A Powershell script executed in SSIS doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: vb.net, powershell, ssis

I have a simple (test) Powershell script, it creates an empty file. The script runs fine executed manually in Powershell. However it does nothing when executed in SSIS. 
I've tried executing it in an Execute Process task and also in a VB.Net Script task. 
Both times Poweshell seems to open (I see the screen come up and close quickly), however the file that the script tries to create doesn't get created.
Any ideas how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: not familiar with the specific SSIS gotcha's but you can get a better idea of what is going on if you add a `Read-Host` at the end of your script, which will keep the window open so you can see if there are any errors.  If it is still closing immediately I would check to see if SSIS has a different executionpolicy setting than the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` is what made it work. So now what I am passing is:

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file "\\SERVER\Share\Script.ps1"
```

This is where I got this tip - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1714552-147-1.aspx

After I added this, `Read-Host` started working also and paused the execution of the script.